# Appmaker EAP from TT whitelisting

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm having an issue with one of my whitelisted domains, it's still under the old TT program and not under the new EAP.

I have no answer from the usual people whom handled this durning TT, who should I contact?

JD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To transition from TT to EAP, you'll need to go through the same application process that was announced on 11/30.

Basically you need to be running G Suite Business, and the applicant needs to be the domain admin for that domain.

Here's the App Maker Landing Page that we published:
https://gsuite.google.com/appmaker

If you sign up here, you'll get an email with the link to the actual EAP application form.

Also, we are currently backlogged with EAP applications, so it could take more than a week, but we're hoping to speed up the process as we get up and running full steam.

Thanks for your patience!
-Chris (App Maker)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet at this point would probably be to contact Google Cloud directly via a support ticket, as referenced here https://connect.googleforwork.com/docs/DOC-18620, and outline what you're seeing.